# How to solve Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' without overriding webpack config

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have a react app and all of a sudden I got the below errors while I run npm start:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js 118:12-25
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in .......
webpack compiled with 1 error and 1 warning
```

I manage to handle it with adding fallback to webpack.config.js like below:

```
.....
 resolve: {
      // This allows you to set a fallback for where webpack should look for modules.
      // We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
      // if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
      // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/253

      fallback:{
        "fs":false
      },
}
```

it solved the problem but I don't want to override webpack.config.js because if I remove my node modules and some one else tries to npm install then he will get the error again.

how can I solve the error without overriding webpack.config.js?

Comment: Your webpack config should not get overwritten just because you do a npm install.

Comment: If I am not suppose to override webpack config so how to handle that error? I can not run npm start

Comment: You are supposed to edit webpack config

Comment: oh I underestand. so if somebody wants to develop my project and start installing packages with npm install he will get the error and he should also edit webpack config and I do not want this.

Comment: Where is `webpack.config.js` located?

Comment: @Konrad node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js

Comment: You should have your own `webpack.config.js` in the root directory of the project

Comment: @Konrad If I have my own webpack config in root when someone tries to run npm install , is this webpack config in root consider as config for webpack? what will happen to config in webpack in node modules?